# Can I run a Python Selenium bot on cPanel and store it's data in a MySQL db?

Tags: python, mysql, laravel, selenium-webdriver, cpanel

Okay, so the scope of the project is this, I've been scraping data using Selenium and storing it locally in an SQLite db as a proof of concept on a promising idea I have. 2 challenges with this approach though, 1. I need to keep my laptop running for it to work which obviously is not ideal, and 2. since I'd like to now create a web app for users to consume said data I've been looking to try and kill 2 birds with one stone here. So my thought process is this, create the web app in Laravel, connect it to a db and upload it to a cPanel shared hosting account I have (the easy part) then upload my bot to the same hosting and direct it's data to the same app db so retrieval is easy and straightforward.
Why cPanel? Because I already have an account and I'd like my MVP's proof-of-concept to be as inexpensive as possible.
So, is my approach possible and if so, how can I upload the bot and run it on cPanel? Btw, I have no access to the hosting's terminal.